# How to remove the item content from my alerts templete

Tags: 2013, development, alert, site-settings, custom-alert-templates

I am working on a team site that contains an announcement list & also on an enterprise wiki site. i set a general alerts for all users to be notified when any item is added/edited/deleted . currently the notification email will be embedding the item content in the email body. so if a user add a new wiki page, then all the content will be send by email, which we find not very reliable, as some pages are quite long.

So i am trying to remove this from my `alerttemplates.xml` located at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML` , but seems the template is very long and i am unable to determine which XML component/s  i need to remove ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Ok i tried modifying the announcement list alert template as follow:-

```
<ImmediateNotificationExcludedFields>ID;MySubsUrl;ListUrl;MobileUrl;Title;Body;Expires;Author;Editor;Modified_x0020_By;Created_x0020_By;_UIVersionString;ContentType;TaskGroup;IsCurrent;Attachments;NumComments;</ImmediateNotificationExcludedFields>
            <DigestNotificationExcludedFields>ID;MySubsUrl;ListUrl;MobileUrl;Title;Body;Expires;Author;Editor;Modified_x0020_By;Created_x0020_By;_UIVersionString;ContentType;TaskGroup;IsCurrent;Attachments;NumComments;</DigestNotificationExcludedFields>
</Properties>
```

& as follow :-

```
 <Properties>
            <ImmediateNotificationExcludedFields>ID;Alerts_link_modify;Alerts_link_view;Alerts_mobile_view;Title;Body;Expires;Author;Editor;Modified_x0020_By;Created_x0020_By;_UIVersionString;ContentType;TaskGroup;IsCurrent;Attachments;NumComments;</ImmediateNotificationExcludedFields>
            <DigestNotificationExcludedFields>ID;Alerts_link_modify;Alerts_link_view;Alerts_mobile_view;Title;Body;Expires;Author;Editor;Modified_x0020_By;Created_x0020_By;_UIVersionString;ContentType;TaskGroup;IsCurrent;Attachments;NumComments;</DigestNotificationExcludedFields>
        </Properties>
```

but still i get these inside the alert message , although i have excluded the following `MySubsUrl;ListUrl;MobileUrl`:-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alerttemplates XML will have templates for several list types. You will find the structure of the templates enclosed in

```
<AlertTemplate Type="List"  Name="SPAlertTemplateType.GenericList">
```

and a similar tag for announcement list. However modifying the alertemplate XML directly is not recommended. Also, if you modify the XML, the template change will apply for all the lists created through that list template. You can still have a look at [this](http://dirkvandenberghe.com/2008/01/08/how-to-change-the-alert-email-notification-message-for-announcements.html) post. Another way would be to write a custom solution and trigger an email with required format when an announcement is added/modified.

Comment: why it is not recommended to modify the default template ?, what i will do is that i will copy the existing template then do my modification to the new copy , after that i will update the defualt alert template to use the custom template, using "stsadm -o updatealerttemplates...". it is easier in my case to simply modify the default template, as i only need to remove the item content at this stage..

Comment: also at the current stage i do not have any problem in changing the alerts for all the lists in my current web application... as i do not want to include the item content in any situation ..

Comment: sure if you are OK with changing the template for all the lists you can take that approach.Modifying the <ImmediateNotificationExcludedFields> and <DigestNotificationExcludedFields> as given in the referenced article might help !

Comment: aha ok thanks but do u know which template is responsible for the enterprise wiki ? as the link talks about the announcement list only

Comment: probably modifying the template node for document library might help.

Comment: Kelker , can you check my edit to the original question ,, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the your custom template; to find the blocks of information that you need to remove or comment you should see this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/bb862021(v=office.14).aspx